# didSelectRowAt is not getting called

Tags: swift

I have a tableView, I set the delegate and datasource but when tapping on a cell, the didSelectRowAt function is not getting called.
This is my code:

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "DropdownCell"

extension ReportVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return showMenu ? companies.count : .zero //If show menu is true the tableView needs to be shown, so we are returning the number of companies in the array, if the show menu is flase the tableView does NOT needs to be shown, so we are returning zero.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CompanyCell
    cell.companyNameLabel.text = companies[indexPath.row]

    let bgColorView = UIView()
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.appBlueAccent

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView

    return cell
}

//TODO: add arrow to indicate the dropdown list, adjust the select company label to the side of the screen
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Select Company", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.appWhite, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDropDown), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.appBlueAccent

    return button
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func configureTableView(){
    tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
    tableView.rowHeight = 50
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.appWhite
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.register(CompanyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    view.addSubview(tableView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
        tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),

        ])
}


@objc func handleDropDown(){

    showMenu = !showMenu
    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

    for i in 0..<companies.count{
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
        indexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }

    if showMenu {
        tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
    }else{
        tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
    }

}
}
```

This is my extension of my ReportVC, In the report VC I'm calling configureTableView and set the showMenu and tableView variables.
I tried to print the indexPath or actually just even print a string to see if the didSelectRowAt is getting called, but nothing happens.

Comment: This might not be relevant, but your `handleDropDown` is wrong. You need to be calling `performBatchUpdates` here.

Comment: Are you using Storyboard? Maybe you have a segue that interferes with `didSelectRowAt`. You should only use one of them.

Comment: @Koen Thanks but I'm not using the Storyboard.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a _minimal_ reproducible example project by starting with a Single View app template? If so, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the tap is being swallowed up my the cell's contents.  What I would do is use the Debug View Hierarchy to see the layout.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to remove the UILabel I have in the cell but it still won't work.